# XSL comparing two element values and changing it

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to make small modifications to the xml file I get through XSL. XSL is not really my thing but I managed to do some previous modifications but I'm stuck at comparing two values of different elements and then changing based on the condition. The condition is, if value1 is less than value2 then add 10 to value2. Below is the .xml

```
    <Parent1>
        <Parent2>
            <VALUE1>10:30</VALUE1>
            <VALUE2>15:30</VALUE2>
            <VALUE3>13:00</VALUE3>
            <VALUE4>13:30</VALUE4>
            <VALUE5>13:30</VALUE5>
            <VALUE6>13:00</VALUE6>
            <VALUE7>13:30</VALUE7>
            <VALUE8>13:00</VALUE8>
            <VALUE9>13:00</VALUE9>
            <VALUE10>13:00</VALUE10>
            <CHECK1>12</CHECK1>
            <CHECK2>18</CHECK2>
            <CHECK3>2</CHECK3>
            <FINAL></FINAL>
        </Parent2>
    </Parent1>
```

I was thinking of something like

```
        <xsl:template match="*"> 
                    <xsl:copy> 
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/> 
                    </xsl:copy> 
        </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="/">    
                           <xsl:for-each select="Parent2">
                            <xsl:if test="VALUE1 < VALUE2">
                           <!---- add 10 to VALUE2   ------>

    </xsl:template>  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Could anyone please help me or point me in the right direction, as I said I dont really use XSL. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The condition is, if value1 is less than value2 then add 10 to value2.

This means you only ever want to change value2 - so it would be best to have a dedicated template matching value2 (in addition to a general *identity transform* template to copy all other nodes without modification):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="VALUE2">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="../VALUE1 &lt; .">
                <xsl:value-of select=". + 10"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

or just:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="VALUE2[. > ../VALUE1] ">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select=". + 10"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Edit:

***in response to your edited question:***

XSLT 1.0 has no concept of time as a data type. In order to compare times, you need to convert each string to the number of seconds it represents:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="VALUE2">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:variable name="time" select="60*substring-before(., ':') + substring-after(., ':')" />
        <xsl:variable name="val1" select="../VALUE1" />
        <xsl:variable name="time1" select="60*substring-before($val1, ':') + substring-after($val1, ':')" />
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$time1 &lt; $time">
                <xsl:value-of select="10 + floor($time div 60) "/>
                <xsl:value-of select="format-number($time mod 60, ':00') "/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thanks a million, and if I may ask for a little help too, if the values are actually in a time/hour format (ie. 12:30, 08:30), I wanted to use substring on values and compare the hours themselves but I dont know how to put it :(

Comment: @user2842773 I am afraid I don't follow. Why don't you edit your question, add a new example and clarify what the condition and the expected result are. -- Also state if you are using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: ok, so if the values under elements look like this, so its basically time values in hours in minutes, but it can also look like 60:30, so in the case when value1 is less than value2 I would need to add 10 to value2. (i.e. value1=10:00, value2=15:30 the new value2 should look like 25:30)

Comment: @user2842773 Do you mean add 10 **hours** to the time? -- Also please state which version of XSLT you are using.

Comment: <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0", yes I would add 10 hours, but the thing is, since it's not in an actual time format, I thought that I should just compare the first 2 chars of the value, thus the substring idea.

Comment: @user2842773 If you compare only the first 2 chars of the values, then 10:15 will **not** be less than 10:45. I am not sure what you mean by "*it's not in an actual time format*".

Comment: true, that was very dumb of me, sry

Comment: that works perfectly, thank you sir for your time and patience. Would you please be kind to suggest on where to start learning XSLT, I believe it might get handy in the future. I know there's a ton of online material probably, but if you'd suggest some specific book or something like that I would be grateful.

Comment: @user2842773 I am afraid I am not the correct person to answer that, being self-taught myself.